# QFileDialog (PyQt) dsiplaying sequence of files as one entry

Tags: qt, pyqt, pyqt4, sequences, qfiledialog

I would like the QFileDialog in PyQt4 to display sequences of files as one entry.

For example.

image0001.dpx,
image0002.dpx,
image0003.dpx

Could be shortened to

image%04d.dpx OR image####.dpx

Does anyone have a solution to this or an idea of how to approach it?

Thanks

Comment: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qfiledialog.html#selectedFiles returns QStringList and you can change or parse or join this list, is what you need, I don't think that Qt can give you custom output.

Comment: This is what directories are for. Put each sequence of files in its own directory (named *image####.dpx*, or whatever) - then QFileDialog will display them "as one entry".

Answer (score 1):

You must be from vfx :) .. anyways there are few ways to do this. glob can be used and the best thing is using something like this http://code.google.com/p/pyseq/ then build your own file dialogbox.